# Novice inquiry: what should the error term syntax be for my data?

Tags: r, lme4

I'm new to **R** and **lme4** and am having trouble understanding how I should code the error term for my analysis

My data looks like this:

- Elevation
- Cover
- Treatment
- Date
- Flux

The study is to see how elevation (either upper or lower) and community (meadow or aspen) affect soil flux (the [continuous] response variable).

We initially included a treatment, but other analyses we've run indicate that it doesn't have much effect, so we are excluding it for now.
We repeatedly took the flux measurements from the same plots over the course of a couple years. We want to run a mixed linear model instead of a repeated measures ANOVA

My model currently looks like this:

```
fluxmodel <- lmer(Flux ~ Cover*Elevation + (1 | Date), data = mydata)
summary(fluxmodel)
anova(fluxmodel)
```

my question is what I should do with the error term, which is currently `(1|Date)`? I haven't found any helpful explanation for the differences between `|` and `/` in the error term or which syntax would be best to use in a repeated measures scenario like this. Given my experimental design, how should I code the error?

Comment: Can you provide additional detail about the structure of your data? If I'm reading things correctly, you have repeated measures nested w/in plots (cover?). IE- from your description, `Date` appears to be a time indicator, not a cluster, which is not how you have the model coded.

Comment: In general, `... (1|cluster)` is used for random intercepts for a 2-level cluster variable. while `... (1|L3 / L2)` is used for a 3-level model where L2 is nested w/in L3